# lombok @Builder type cast error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, design-patterns, lombok

I am new in `lombok` library. I am using `@Builder` pattern of `lombok` but it return generic of `Object` type:

```
@Data
@Builder
public class Schedule<T>
{
    private String frequency;
    private T properties;
}
```

From calling class:

```
Abc abc=new Abc();
//other
Schedule<Object> schedule=Schedule.builder().frequency( "ankit" ).properties( abc ).build();
```

i want result in `Schedule<Abc>` but getting `Schedule<Object>`.

Thanks and respond as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a issue of lombok.you need to type cast it to Your class `Abc`. For type cast you need to follow syntax:

```
T<M> t=T.<M>builder()
        .variablename("set value")
        .build();
```

as answered by @Micha: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51873129/6097074

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass `Abc` as generic parameter to `builder()`:

`Schedule<Abc> schedule = Schedule.<Abc>builder()
    .frequency( "ankit" )          ^^^
    .properties( abc )
    .build();`